# Removing Windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I realize that this looks like a duplicate question but it's not.

I have an ASUS eee notebook with Windows 10. I want to remove Windows 10 and install ubuntu.

I've wandered through the other answers and they all start with "pop in a bootable CD or USB then follow the set of selections offered"

Problem is that the ubuntu screen of selections never comes up. I have three different USB sticks that I've used before that don't work and two CD disks that I've used before and none will either boot or come up the the selections screen. I've even tried a Redhat 7.2 CD that didn't work. I build the USB sticks on a 16.04 machine using Create startup disk with various ISOs from ubuntu.

The closest I've gotten is a choice of "Help me boot from the CD" which seems to install some kind of secondary MBR that offers a choice of Ubuntu or Windows. When I choose Ubuntu I get an error 000007 that then forces me down the path to a Windows boot.

I will happily format the drive and start from scratch if I could get to GParted but Windows says I have to format the CD in order to use it. (Same with the USB)

It seems that Windows is so aggressive about letting the ubuntu software near the hardware that it won't let grub near it.

I'm tapped on ideas. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which Eee PC is it? It sounds like it may be a problem with Fast Startup or Secure Boot.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) is a useful article that will help you with the USB. The only other issue that can arise is with UEFI/BIOS but this can easily be resolved with a couple of simple steps:

1. Follow the steps in the linked article to create a Bootable Ubuntu USB.
2. Restart your computer and repeatedly tap F2 as your manufacturer logo shows (for Asus it is F2, so you would want to check what it is for your PC). This will open up your BIOS.
3. In your BIOS, use your arrow keys to enter the "BOOT" section.
4. In there increase the priority of USB:HDD/USB:FLASH DRIVE (whichever you have) to the top of the list. (there are instructions on how to do this in the BIOS itself, so look around)

Finally, plug the USB into your computer, save these changes and exit. It should boot into the Live USB, if it doesn't restart and try again!

Hope this help!

Comment: I rebuilt the USB using rufus the BIOS now shows the USB as a UEFI device. Moved it to boot #1, disabled the windows boot manager, Saved and exited. The USB has an LED to show activity which blinks during boot but it won't display the install screens. It just goes back to the BIOS. I'm using 15.10 i386 ISO. Not sure where or what's going wrong.

Comment: Another thing you could try is switching to Legacy mode, sometimes that solves the issue